# Keycloak ldap registration user sync

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I have an ldap user federation configured with sync registrations ON.

Now when I register a new user, this user is synced to ldap but not saved into local DB (synced back from ldap).

```
[org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProvider] (default task-21) LDAP User invalid. ID doesn't match. ID from LDAP [test@mailinator.com], LDAP ID from local DB: [ ]
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR
Error   user_not_found
Details     
grant_type  authorization_code
code_id     7ac8c3c7-c9d3-413a-bb83-401047925b92
client_auth_method  client-secret

LOGIN
auth_method     openid-connect
auth_type   code
redirect_uri    ***/sso/login
consent     no_consent_required
code_id     7ac8c3c7-c9d3-413a-bb83-401047925b92
username    ***

REGISTER
auth_method     openid-connect
auth_type   code
register_method     form
redirect_uri    ***/sso/login
code_id     7ac8c3c7-c9d3-413a-bb83-401047925b92
email   ***
username    ***
```